# CAReplicatorLayer with CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation, calayer

I started using `CAReplicatorLayer` to get replications of a `CAShapeLayer`.

The `instanceTransform` property of the layer which I use to move the replications does work fine but `instanceAlphaOffset` and the other color offsets (e.g. `instanceBlueOffset`) have no effect. What can I do to make it work?

Can I subclass `CAReplicatorLayer` to define custom properties that change on the replications? I'd love to change the fill and `strokeColor` of the `CAShapeLayer` with every replications.
Or is this somehow else (without subclassing) possible?

Comment: I'm guessing that the color and alpha properties modify the background color of the shape layer which is not the same as the full color.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I guess too...now that you say it ;) Do you think there's a way to adjust the fill and strokeColor with the replications? E.g. have the fill behave differently to the stroke color?

Comment: Hi @Max ever found a solution?